# Lock listview scroll on an event

Tags: java, android, android-listview

How do I freeze the listview scroll when keyboard pops up and then regain scroll after keyboard is hidden.
I cannot seem to start anywhere

Answer (score 0):

In On ScrollState Change check keyboard is open or not:

```
   public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {   
  //check keyboard is open?    
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity()
        .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

if (imm.isAcceptingText()) {
    writeToLog("Software Keyboard was shown");
} else {
    writeToLog("Software Keyboard was not shown");
}
}
```

and stop listview with

```
   listView.setScrollContainer(false);
```